# How to deduce an object from the filter, but not a boolean?

Tags: reactjs

How to deduce an object from the filter, but not a boolean?
I do a search, and now I get true or false, but how do I get an object?

```
services.getDataUsers(callback => callback.filter(i => {
    // return i.name.indexOf(term) > -1; // true & false (term - input value)
    console.log(i) // i - object
}));
```

console.log(i):
[image]

Comment: what are you trying to do? include sample input and output. If the argument you get is an array then avoid naming it `callback`.

Comment: Question is not clear. But incase you are looking to print only the filtered object to console, you can use map operator. Try `services.getDataUsers(callback => callback.filter(i => i.name.indexOf(term) > -1).map(i=>console.log(i)}));`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `callback` is an array (if it is, it is a bad name IMHO), you can use the [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method to get the first element matching the provided test function.

```
services.getDataUsers(arr => arr.find(i => i.name.indexOf(term) > -1));
```